# ffmpeg - how to copy exactly the video settings except for the resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to change the resolution of my .flv file. I have tried "ffmpeg -i file.flv -s 1280x720 -acodec copy file2.flv", but the output file has different video encoding settings. I have added "-vcodec libx264" which makes the output settings closer to the input settings, but there are still little differences such as fps. I realize that I could probably use mediainfo and figure out how to format that information in a way ffmpeg can use, but that seems like a very clunky solution. Is there a way for ffmpeg to copy the encoding settings from the input and apply them to the output with a resolution change?

Comment: "-vcodec copy" (if that isn't what you want then...AFAIK there isn't)

Comment: @rogerdpack You cant use copy and change resolution.

Comment: ok yeah you'll need to re-encode it, specifying your own bitrate or quality settings https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 FWIW, as you described basically.